# selective removal of characters following a pattern using R

Tags: r, regex

How to selectively remove characters from a string following a pattern?

I wish to remove the 7 figures and the preceding colon.

For example:

```
"((Northern_b:0.005926,Tropical_b:0.000000)N19:0.002950"
```

should become

```
"((Northern_b,Tropical_b)N19"
```

Comment: `gsub("[0-9.]{8}", "", x)` where `x` is the input string.

Comment: Shenglin's answer is correct - this comment doesn't quite give the desired result.

Answer (score 2):

```
x <- "((Northern_b:0.005926,Tropical_b:0.000000)N19:0.002950"
gsub("[:]\\d{1}[.]\\d{6}", "", x)
```

The `gsub` function does string replacement and replaces all matched found in the string (see `?gsub`).  An alternative, if you want something with a more friendly names is `str_replace_all` from the `stringr` package.

The regular expression makes use of the `\\d{n}` search, which looks for digits.  The integer indicates the number of digits to look for.  So `\\d{1}` looks for a set of digits with length 1.  `\\d{6}` looks for a set of digits of length 6.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub('[:][0-9.]+','',x)
[1] "((Northern_b,Tropical_b)N19"
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and question edits (bluntness is key...) - you guys are great.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to solve this problem

```
library(stringr)
str1 <- c("((Northern_b:0.005926,Tropical_b:0.000000)N19:0.002950")

str_replace_all(str1, regex("(:\\d{1,}\\.\\d{1,})"), "")

#[1] "((Northern_b,Tropical_b)N19"
```